# How to convert a String to the correct Enum constant (multiple Enums implementing a common interface)?

Tags: java, interface, enums, type-conversion

Suppose I have an interface...

```
public interface Feature
{
    public abstract void doSmth();
}
```

... and multiple enums implementing that interface:

// First enum

```
public enum FeatureA implements Feature
{
    A1
    {
        @Override public void doSmth() { System.out.println("A ==== A1"); }
    },

    A2
    {
        @Override public void doSmth() { System.out.println("A ==== A2"); }
    };

    @Override public abstract void doSmth();
}
```

//Second enum

```
public enum FeatureB implements Feature
{
    B1 
    {
        @Override public void doSmth() { System.out.println("B ==== B1"); }
    },

    B2
    {
        @Override public void doSmth() { System.out.println("B ==== B2"); }
    },

    B3
    {
        @Override public void doSmth() { System.out.println("B ==== B3"); }
    };

    @Override public abstract void doSmth();
}
```

// and many other enums implementing Feature

Now suppose I assemble a set of Strings corresponding to the names of enum constants like this (this is necessary for the third party code)...

```
Set<String> singleEnum = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
singleEnum.add("A2");
singleEnum.add("A1");
```

... and later I need to convert each String in such a set to the enum constant and then apply the doSmth() method. singleEnum contains names of FeatureA constants only, so I'm able to apply the valueOf(String) method in this case:

```
for (String s : singleEnum)
{
    FeatureA.valueOf(s).doSmth();
}
```

But what if the Strings in the set correspond to varying enum constants? E.g.:

```
Set<String> multipleEnums = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
multipleEnums.add("A1");
multipleEnums.add("B2");
multipleEnums.add("A2");
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
for (String s : multipleEnums)
{
    Feature./* convert s to the correct enum */.doSmth();
}
```

Is there an easy way to do that? The only method Eclipse allows to apply to Feature is Feature.class, and I don't really know how to proceed from there.
I'm dealing with huge datasets, so performance is important.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Map with the name of every enum

```
static final Map<String, Feature> map = ...
static <F extends Enum & Feature> void addEnums(F... features) {
    for(F f: features)
       map.put(f.name(), f);
}

addEnums(FeatureA.values());
addEnums(FeatureB.values());
```

Comment: This is pretty much the way I did it in my current project, where I have exactly this requirement. One point, though: I use a lazy-initializing idiom for the map because otherwise one must either call `addEnums` explicitly or do it in a static initializer, which can cause circular dependency problems.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to do that?

I don't think so.  If it was just one enum you could use the enum's static `valueOf` method to do the conversion.  But with multiple enums you would need to call each of them ... and deal with the IllegalArgumentExceptions.

I think you will have to resort to creating and populating a `Map<String, Feature>` for all of the enum values.